# Not as crude as it looks, rather studious

Tags: riddle, word

> The endless semen, not many polyester makes not me —
>   the heart's duplicated of a studious half-year.
>   What comes after semi without individuality,
>   I call the heart.
>
> Next, yes!
>   Easter has come! Oh no...not in full. The very beginning's quite missing.
>   Vow and take a well. The con with an ant.
>   Either will do. But no half-blood will I stand.
>
> Sounds the samest. Err...
>   But no hesitation would do;
>   the unlawful and the unworms don’t  last.
>   Worms? Don’t eww.
>
> Preceded it is by the
>   successor of the alpha, starter in kites
>   With two big ladoos stacked between
>   Wholesome they are, but in these terms, won’t make you last.

---

#### **What's the word I describe?**

---

To clarify:

> The word has 8 letters. It refers to a "studious half-year".

Comment: Soha, maybe accept @Ankoganit's answer, since they fully and correctly answered the question as originally posed? :)

Comment: @puzzledPig Ok, thanks for the advice! Edited your answer. Check it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The word is probably:

> Semester.

The endless semen, not many polyester makes not me —
the heart's duplicated of a studious half-year.

> Seme(n)+polyester-poly(=many) gives semester, which is almost the word with the central letter `e` duplicated.   Of course, "studious half-year" is what it means.

What comes after semi without individuality, I call the heart.
Next, yes!
Easter has come! Oh no...not in full. The very beginning's quite missing.

> Semi-I(individuality)+(y)es+(eas)ter also yields the same word.   The letter coming after sem(i), `e` is the heart, or the centre of the word.

Vow and take a well. The con with an ant.
Either will do. But no half-blood will I stand.

> Likely refers to the `y` that got removed.  It's not a vowel (vow... well) or consonant (con...ant), but a "half-blood".

Comment: Well done! You were very fast! Extra two lines added.

Comment: @Soha I don't recommend editing it too often. Decide for once what to post, and then let the voters decide what goes with the riddle and what doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

#### Adding on to @Ankoganit's answer...

Sounds the samest. Err...

> SEMESTER sounds like "samest-er".`

But no hesitation would do;
the unlawful and the unworms don’t last.
Worms? Don't eww.

> In a school SEMESTER, hesitating in your answers would make you fail. Similarly, the people who don't follow the rules ("the unlawful") are penalised. What on earth does the "unworms" mean? The last line tells us not to be disgusted, so perhaps the following lines will explain this.

Preceded it is by the

> WORM comes after [insert what comes out of what comes after this line].

successor of the alpha, starter in kites
With two big ladoos stacked between

> "successor of the alpha" is probably **B**. (Alpha = A, B comes after A.)
>  "starter in kites" is **K**, as it's the letter which begins 'kites'.
>  "two big ladoos" are most probably **OO**,  since O is the letter which most closely resembles a laddoo.
>  So, this and the previous lines together yield — **BOOK**WORM. Whether or not you've to be a bookworm to do well in your school SEMESTERs is subjective, though.

Wholesome they are, but in these terms, won’t make you last.

> Refers to the "two big ladoos". Ladoo is a round-shaped sweet. It's perfectly delicious and "wholesome". But you won't last school terms/SEMESTERs with two big zeroes, which are similar to ladoos in appearance.

Comment: Fully correct! +1